# PHP if variable contains string or multiple words

Tags: php

I have these two variables

```
$page_title = '[[+pagetitle]]';
$title_match = 'Marketing Campaign Calendar';
```

The first is pulling the name of an asset or page and the second are three words I want to search for within those titles. I currently have this if statement which works perfectly as is but I need to add another condition.

```
if(in_array($content_name, $open_modal_types)) {
    // Return view / download buttons
    return '<div class="button-group">
          <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]" 
            class="button secondary open-modal"
            data-mfp-src="#document-modal"
            data-title="[[+pagetitle]]"
            data-type="' . $content_name . '"
            >View</a>
          <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]" class="button secondary" download>Download</a>
        </div>';
  }
  else if($is_binary == '1') {
    // Return download button
    return '<a href="[[~[[+id]]]]" class="button secondary" download>Download</a>';
  }
```

So I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

```
if(in_array($content_name, $open_modal_types)) {
    // Return view / download buttons
    if($page_title contains all of the words in $title_match) {
    return "something";
    }else{
        return '<div class="button-group">
              <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]" 
                class="button secondary open-modal"
                data-mfp-src="#document-modal"
                data-title="[[+pagetitle]]"
                data-type="' . $content_name . '"
                >View</a>
              <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]" class="button secondary" download>Download</a>
            </div>';
    }
  }
  else if($is_binary == '1') {
    // Return download button
    return '<a href="[[~[[+id]]]]" class="button secondary" download>Download</a>';
  }
```

I've tried using strpos and preg_match but couldn't get it to work. I don't know if I have too many if statements or what. Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: `I've tried using strpos and preg_match but couldn't get it to work.` I can't see any of it. Where is that code?

Comment: @Andreas I removed it but I was trying `if(strpos('marketing', $page_title ) {
    return "something";
    }` just to test for one word

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this

```
<?php
$words = "test1 test2 test3";
function containsAllWords($title, $words) {
  $arrWords = explode(" ", $words);
  foreach ($arrWords as $word) {
    if (strpos($title, $word) === false) {
      return false; // one word is not found, so it doesn't contain ALL
    }
  }
  return true; // if we got here, it contains all the words
}
var_dump(containsAllWords("test1 test2 test4", $words)); // false
var_dump(containsAllWords("test1 test2 test3 test4", $words)); // true
```

Comment: I tried putting a function similar to yours inside that first `if(in_array($content_name, $open_modal_types)) { }` but I seem to have a syntax error somewhere. Too large to include in my response.

Comment: Well, did you try with my function? Add it on top of the page, then just check with `if (containsAllWords($page_title, $title_match)) {`

Comment: Ya I copied your function I just changed the variables and put it inside of that other if statement. I'll keep playing with it. Thanks

Comment: Remember to mark answer if it helped you. If not, tell me how I can help you.

Comment: I am adding the function at the top of the page right underneath my variables. Even a simple function is white screening my page. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The exact function I posted? Or another one? Paste the code. Maybe you have a syntax error you didn't notice. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` right after <?php, so the error will be displayed on the page and you'll be able to debug easily.

Comment: The error I get `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare containsAllWords() (previously declared in /data/www/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/76.include.cache.php:22) in /data/www/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/76.include.cache.php on line 22` I wonder if it's trying to execute too many times since there is an array of files on the page?

Comment: Well there you have it, you have the function definition twice (on line 22 and some other line). You can only have the function definition once. This includes when you `include` a file.

Comment: It's not repeated anywhere those lines are the start and end of the function

Comment: Do you include the file with the definition more than once then?

Comment: I also think I might have my thought process a little wrong. There is a list of files or assets on the page. I want to tweak the download link for those whos titles contain the words I'm looking for. So I think I need a foreach in there somewhere.

Comment: No it's just in one snippet

Answer (score 0):

may be instead of this

```
if($page_title contains all of the words in $title_match)
```

use preg_match:

```
$title_match = '('.str_replace(' ',')&(', $title_match).')';
if(preg_match('/'.$title_match.'/i', $title_match))
```

But you should be sure that $title_match not contains special symbols, or filter it by \

Answer (score 0):

So the site I am working on is built in Modx which is fairly new to me. Instead of my original solution I was trying to attempt, I created a new content type within the CMS and wrote my modifications for that content type only. This makes much better sense than what I was trying to do before. 
Any other Modx users out there, feel free to reach out to me if you want more details on my solution and what I was trying accomplish.

Thanks to those for trying to help.